# Insert new element in mongoDB collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection in mongoDB "employees" that contains the following:

- id : type string
- Holidays :  type ***array***
- Name :  type string
- Domain : type string.

What I want to do is to add one (*or more*) new  holiday in my **Holidays array**.

I have tried this in my employeeRepository

```
    public async Task<Holiday> AddHolidays(List<Holiday> item)
    {
        await _context.Employees.InsertOneAsync(item);
        return await GetHoliday(item.id);
    }
```

but I think this is not the right way to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting in an array can be done by the $push operator
I think that you can use UpdateBuilder.PushWrapped Method

```
employeesCollection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", MyObject.Id), 
                    UpdateBuilder.PushWrapped("Holidays", item)
```